# inserting php session id into database from php://input callback

Tags: php, mysql

i have a callback page, that i am using to insert data in a db. when i load this page. and echo $_SESSION['user_id']. it echos the user_id, and inserts it into the db. however when i am trying to insert the data while doing the callback function, the $_SESSSION['user_id'] is ignored and the other data is succesfully inserted. why is this?

```
echo $_SESSION['user_id'];    
$decodedJSON = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);    
$account = $decodedJSON['account'];    
$query_insert = "insert into video (account,userid) values ($account,$_SESSION['user_id'])";    
$result_insert = mysql_query($query_insert);
```

When i refresh the page, $_SESSION['user_id'] is inserted. But when i try to run the callback function, $account is inserted, but $_SESSION['user_id'] is not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of how this all fits together with your code sample, but if you're trying to pass somethign to stanard input and then run the PHP, you also need to pass the sessionID.

When you call the code from your borwser, cookies magically handle all that for you, and the sessions ID is passed in a cookie. But if you're calling from another source, cookies are not passed.

I could explain how to do it, but nothing better than the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php - basically append the SID to the end of hte URL.

But note the comment about "session.use_trans_sid" which is disabled by default and needs to be enabled in php.ini